# sql syntax error in JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join

i have this simple SQL join query, which is giving me a syntax error on the second `FROM`

```
SELECT * FROM ##temporderstable P 
FROM supporder Y join backorder ON P.catalogid = Y.backorder 
GROUP BY P.catalogid
```

i can't figure out whats wrong with it, any hints?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to change the second from clause to a join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two FROM clauses like that...

You might mean JOIN but you'd need another ON condition:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ##temporderstable P 
  JOIN supporder Y ON P.catalogid = Y.backorder 
  JOIN backorder B ON B.xxxxxxxxx = P.xxxxyyyyy
 GROUP BY P.catalogid;
```

The second ON would need to reference a column of B and a column of either P or Y.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    ##temporderstable P 
    JOIN supporder Y 
    ON P.catalogid = Y.backorder 
GROUP BY P.catalogid
```

Also, your query doesn't have any aggregate functions, so you should think of the need for GROUPing on `P.catalogid`

Answer (score 1):

Your query has two FROM clause. It should be something like this.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ##temporderstable P 
INNER JOIN 
    supporder Y 
ON 
    P.catalogid = Y.backorder 
GROUP BY 
    P.catalogid
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `From` clause is not applicable. You have to use only one and inside that you have to join two tables.